# Как правильно создать страницу для кастомного action-a CrudController-a в Symfony (6) Easy Admin (4)?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

Я добавил свой кастомный Action в Easy admin, который импортирует (должен будет импортировать, когда закончу) данные в БД путём получения CSV файла с данными (В моём случае товарами) из формы, следуя советам [официальной документации](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/actions.html#adding-custom-actions)

У каждого дефолтного экшна есть свой html, куда редиректит по его триггеру. Например, фиолетовая кнопка из скриншота "Add Product" редиректит на "crud/new". Так как мне создать  такой же для своего кастомного экшна Import свою страничку, куда можно будет редиректиться?

[image: Зелёная кнопка Import]

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл полноценный и развёрнутый ответ на свой вопрос [тут](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/easyadminbundle/override-template#overriding-a-core-template).

Если говорить коротко, нужно создавать страничку в той же папке, что и для обычных контроллеров и наследоваться от Изиадминовского базового твига. В четвёртой версии Easyadmin это делается двумя следующими способами (Может, есть и другие):

1. {% extends '@!EasyAdmin/layout.html.twig' %}
2. {% extends ea.templatePath('layout') %}

Без наследования этого твига это будет обыкновенная контроллерская страничка без Админовского сайдбара слева.